# does Ubuntu installation come with wireless usb drivers?

Tags: wireless, software-installation

I have an Ubuntu ISO on a USB which I used to install Ubuntu on a workstation that can only connect to the internet using a wireless USB adaptor (D-Link DWA-171 A1).

I got the driver software from D-Link, but the install/build fails due to an incomplete gcc library.

Does Ubuntu have in precompiled wireless adaptor drivers so I can connected fast.
I heard maybe drivers for Intel wireless adapters maybe included in the Ubuntu ISO?

I like Linux, but I have to admit Windows 10 sensed the wireless adapter and loaded the drivers so easy.
I plug the adapter with the new Ubuntu install, and it's not even recognized at all.

Comment: Yes, many.Not all. In a terminal window, `sudo journalctl  -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` to see logs. Unplug it, start ` sudo journalctl  -f`, then plug it in. Select just "interesting" lines, and edit your question to add them.

Comment: Your release of Ubuntu may also be useful (it lets us know the age of your software stack, easily spotted from the *year.month* format of Ubuntu releases, though LTS (*long-term-support*) have two stack choices available; the ISO used, eg. 18.04.4 adds that detail).

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: I did the journalctl commands.  After the journalctl -f, I got this output:

Comment: Failed to get featured snaps: persistent network error: Get https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/find?architecture=amd64&category=ubuntu-firstrun&channel=stable&confinement=strict%2Cclassic&fields=base%2Cconfinement%2Ccontact%2Cdescription%2Cdownload%2Clicense%2Cprices%2Cprivate%2Cpublisher%2Crevision%2Csummary%2Ctitle%2Ctype%2Cversion%2Cwebsite%2Cstore-url%2Cmedia%2Ccommon-ids%2Cchannel: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
Jun 19 06:25:01 mike-PW380 CRON[6130]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)

Comment: You can alsways temporarily connect using your phone and install proper drivers. Please add output of `lsusb` to your question. That will show what is the wireless chip and will help to suggest drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu comes with a great many drivers for USB devices. You can find some of them in:

```
ls /usr/lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/
```

Your question may actually be, does the default ubuntu installation come with *all* wireless usb drivers, where the term *all* means the drivers for every USB wireless device including the shiny new device that just came out last week and that you bought yesterday. The answer is, probably not.

New devices are developed and released every day. The manufacturers are in a constant arms race to have a better device with more features and, often, cheaper. In almost every case, they have little or no concern for the 3% or so of Linux users and therefore don't provide a working driver. Even if they love Linux and strive to provide a working driver, what works perfectly in Ubuntu probably won't work correctly in Arch or Manjaro or Gentoo.

Even Ubuntu runs various early, mid and late kernel versions. For instance, Ubuntu 16.04.1 runs kernel version 4.4.0-xx. My fully updated Ubuntu 20.04 runs 5.4.0-xx. Any driver that compiles properly for 4.4.0-xx and it's associated gcc version, probably won't compile correctly in 5.4.0-xx.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support

As a consequence, *if* a Linux driver is provided in the package with the shiny new USB wireless device that you bought yesterday, it undoubtedly works for some Linux distribution running some kernel but it may not be yours.

Since the drivers in the default Ubuntu installation are, for the reasons above, a year or two old, most older devices, such as my TP-Link TL-WN722N, Version 1, work perfectly. The driver and firmware are built-in to all recent, that is, not end-of-life, Ubuntu versions.

There are two problems with just buying a two or three year old device. First, they were developed before 5 gHz wireless was widespead; mine only does 2.4 gHz. As a consequence, very high speeds, such as 802.11AC or 802.11AX, will not be available.Second, it is almost impossible to find an older wireless device on the shelf at the store and almost impossible to find older USB devices at on-line marketplaces such as Amazon and many others.

Finally, Amazon is a great resource because, first, if the device is listed as available for order, then it’s currently produced and, well, available. Second, Amazon encourages customer questions and answers. You can search for USB wireless devices and, under Q&A search for Ubuntu. If you search for the device I mentioned above, you find:

“Yes works fine with Ubuntu.” and: “Also it works with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.” and: “I bought it so I can use it on my ubuntu linux like everyone else is doing, and it worked perfectly”

You can search the Q&A for *Ubuntu* with any USB wireless.

Does the default ubuntu installation come with *all* wireless USB drivers? No. Does the default ubuntu installation come with *many* wireless USB drivers? Yes.

**EDIT**: Using tethering to your phone as @Pilot6 recommends, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential git dkms
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
sudo modprobe 88XXau
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: Thanks chili555.  The dlink dwa-171 wireless adapter is a few years old, but I don't mind to get a new one from Amazon that will work with the Ubuntu 20.04 I just installed.  The main problem is it will be a pain to hardwire connect to the router (unless I get Moca set up).  Thanks for the path to the wife drivers!!!

Comment: As @Pilot6 requested, please show us: `lsusb`.

Comment: response to "lsusb":  D-Link Corp. 802.11n WLAN Adapter.

Comment: It says a whole lot more. You’ve omitted the details we need the most.

Comment: prepended is "Bus 001 Device 009:  ID 2001:3314"

Comment: output of rtlwifi gives a dozen driver folders.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Totally awesome!  Thank you so much.  First time for usb tethering (my usb cable connected fine to charge my phone battery, but the data connection was failing, so I had to get a new USB cable).  First time also for github, which I know is very popular, so I'm going to learn to use it.

Comment: Awesome! If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: I checked it as solving my problem and note it was a clean and easy solution, and it was resolved quickly.  If I didn't have usb tethering available (or any internet), I'm curious if my brute force method of going to d-link and manually installing the drivers would have eventually worked.

Comment: No. After you installed gcc and the other necessary tools to compile the package, all included in the meta package *build-essential* and after you extracted the zip file from D-Link, you'd have noticed that the driver was built in 2014. Trying to compile it results in an error, as expected: "error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]"  As I said in my answer, I'm confident that the supplied driver worked for some kernel version in 2014 but not your kernel version in 2020. Glad it's now working!